# Counter example to graph coloring heuristic using BFS

Tags: algorithms, graphs, correctness-proof, colorings

I am considering the following heuristic for the graph coloring problem (i.e. to color a graph $G$ using a minimal number of colors so that no two adjacent vertices have the same color):

> Explore the vertices of $G$ in the order that they would be explored by a BFS search (with arbitrary starting vertex) and assign each vertex the lowest numbered color not yet used for one of its neighbors.

Since I don't think this algorithm is correct, I am trying to find a counterexample where coloring a graph in this way does not yield a coloring with the minimal number of colors. Does anyone know of such an example?

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: actually Petersen graph is a counter example .

Comment: I think that published counter-examples of the four-color theorem, usually predating the proof of the theorem should be counter-examples for you. One from Martin Gardner (1975) is there: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Four-ColorTheorem.html. You should find other candidates [on this page](https://www.google.fr/search?q=four-color+theorem+counter-example+-minimal&tbm=isch), and you can easily translate them into graphs. The idea is that if you start with a wrong combination in some part of the graph, you may get blocked, though other choices might work. (to be changed into answer when possible).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299875/what-is-the-counter-example-to-minimality-of-coloring-a-graph-in-bfs-manner/1299951#1299951

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you tried enumerating all graphs of size $\le c$ (for some small constant $c$) to look for a counterexample?  We expect you to make a significant effort to solve it on your own before asking and to show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one:

[image: A graph.]

The labels indicate the intend BFS ordering (alphabetical). A different ordering can produce a different result, so more work would have to be done to get a graph where your BFS approach fails for every starting point (it would probably be very messy too).

Assuming we follow this ordering however, we get the following colouring:

[image: The graph, coloured using the BFS approach.]

The key being that $e$ and $f$ get coloured last, so $c$ removes blue from the possibilities, and $d$ removes red, so $e$ and $f$ must have two new colours.

However this graph is 3-colourable:

[image: The graph, coloured using 3 colours.]

By choosing to use more colours earlier, it relaxes the constraints later.

I'll also throw in a conjecture that this is smallest counterexample, for no other reason than to challenge others to find smaller ones ;).

Answer (score 0):

I think that published alleged "counter-examples" of the four-color theorem, usually predating the proof of the theorem should be rewritable as graph counter-examples for you. There is one [published (as an April Fool's joke) by Martin Gardner in 1975](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Four-ColorTheorem.html).

You should find other candidates on [this page](https://www.google.fr/search?q=four-color%20theorem%20counter-example%20-minimal&tbm=isch), and you can easily translate them into graphs. The idea is that if you start with a wrong combination in some part of the graph, you may get blocked, though other choices might work.